# Remove item from a list and return list as a constant

Tags: flutter, list, dart

I have an enum called Activities, which is defined as such

```
enum Activities {
     Football,
     Basketball,
     Painting
}
```

Now I want to create an enum called ActivityTypes, which is supposed to be defined as such

```
enum ActivityTypes {
    nonSport(types: [Activities.drawing]),
    sport(types: Activities.values..remove(Activities.Painting)),
    all(types: SportType.values);

    final List<Activities> types;
    const ActivityTypes({required this.types});
}
```

Except this doesn't work, because ActivityTypes.sport parameter is not considered a constant, and
I can't just manually define them, as the enum is very long and redundancy should be avoided in case of future edits. Anyone knows how to get around this?

I know this is not the best logic, but I have server-side constraints that are non-negotioable, they return all activities together and I must seperate them in client-side like this.
Thank you for taking the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making `types` a field, you can make it a getter.

```dart
enum ActivityTypes {
  sport();

  List<Activities> get types {
    return switch (this) {
      ActivityTypes.sport => [...Activities.values]..remove(Activities.Painting)
    };
  }
}
```

Note that you also need to copy the list, so I used the [spread operator](https://dart.dev/language/collections#spread-operators) there. You can also use the [`where`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/where.html) method to do the filtering.

---

See also:

- [Declaring enhanced enums](https://dart.dev/language/enums#declaring-enhanced-enums)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, but the whole reason I'm using a constructor is to avoid using switch, trying to keep this as clean as possible, but It is considered as a last resort. Thank you for the help

Comment: IMO this is clean, because the [switch expression](https://dart.dev/language/branches#switch-expressions) is exhaustive, so for every enum value you'll have to define the case in the switch body. The only downside is that you'll have to write each value twice.